# EventHandler in DbContext

Tags: c#, .net-core, dbcontext

I want to override the SaveChangesAsync method from DbContext. Something like this:

```
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    DatabaseChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    return base.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

The problem is that if I subscribe to this event, DbContext will wipe the subscription because is a scoped service and it will create a new instance everywhere is required.
How I can subscribe to this event from another class ?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just inject the thing you need to call when `SaveChangesAsync()` is called?

Comment: DatabaseChanged is an event. I want to know when data changes

Comment: But you're invoking the event manually here (if there are subscribers), you could just do the exact same thing via DI and you wouldn't have this problem. If you had some Handler interface you could inject an e.g.`IEnumerable<IDataChangedHandler>` and then if there are any, invoke each in turn. You're facing an uphill battle trying to get events to place nice with scoped services in a web application, DI is the way forward.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. I just need to create a service that contains an EventHandler and inject it in DbContext (to be able to raise the event) and wherever I need to subscribe the event

Comment: No I mean don't use events at all, use DI to inject handlers and just loop through them and call them. Instead of creating an event handler, subscribing  it (+=) to the DbContext event and then invoking the event instead define an interface and create handlers which implement it, then inject and call those. No events necessary!

Comment: I need to do a major refactor in the code to implement this. Thank you very much, it's help me a lot.